# How to unit test dom manipulating functions in angular tests

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript

I have an angular-cli based project, with a component that has some logic like this:

```
  colorLine() {
      let svgDoc = this.svg.nativeElement.contentDocument;
      JSON.parse(this.stations).forEach(station => {
        station.element = svgDoc.getElementById(station.name);
          station.element.removeAttribute('class');
          if (station.status === 'running') {
            station.element.setAttribute('fill', 'lime');
          }
        return station;
      })
    }
```

I am trying to unit test this with the following test:

```
  it('should color running stations green', async(() => {
    component.svg.nativeElement = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgDoc, 'application/xml');

    component.load();
    expect(component.stations[0].element.getAttribute('fill')).toBe('lime');
  }));
```

where `svgDoc` is a string representation of the element to query. However, I am getting the issue:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

How can I test this sort of functionality?

Comment: looks like this.stations is a string in you component because you do JSON.parse(this.stations). any reason why? so you can't access expect(component.stations[0]...) in u test becuase stations is a string not a javascript object